# Merge Image Functions Results in Incorrect Result in Hybrid Application on iOS - Works in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvas, web

I have this function:

```
   //Merge images
   mergeImages(sig, bg, outputFormat)
   {

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement("canvas");

     var img1 = new Image();
     var img2 = new Image();

     var finalURL = '';

     var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement('canvas');

     document.getElementById("canvasContainer").appendChild(canvas);

     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

     img1.src = '';
     img2.src = '';

     img1.addEventListener('load',function() {
          console.log("loaded img1");

          canvas.width = 100;
          canvas.height = 100;
      });

      img2.addEventListener('load',function() {
           console.log("loaded img2");

          context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 100, 100);
          context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, 100, 100);

          finalURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);

          resolve (finalURL);

          console.log("\n finalURL" + finalURL +"\n");
       });


     setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(img1.complete);
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(img2.complete);
       }, 1000);

     img1.src = bg;

     img2.src = sig;

  });
```

}

This function returns a base64 dataURL of the resulting image from combining 'img1' and 'img2'. The application is built with Ionic (HTML/Typescript).

In the Safari browser, after triggering this function (called via DOM button presses), I always see the correct combined image.

However, when I build this application for iOS (iPad), the result is incorrect, and I have no idea why. That is, only img2 renders in the final image.

No errors are being explicitly thrown.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit (added images):
Correct output in desktop browsers:**

[image: Correct]

**Incorrect image on iOS:**

[image: Incorrect]

Comment: "the result is incorrect" could really use some further explanation.  Based on your description I'm not really sure what you even mean by "combining" two images?

Comment: Your way of waiting for the load events is wrong. What if img2 loads faster? You need to increment a counter and only trigger the drawing when it reaches the number of images. Or, since you seem to be in an environnement supporting Promises, promisify the load events, and wait for Promise.all.

Comment: @DanielBeck oh, sorry about that, I have added images to clarify the correct and incorrect results

Comment: @Kaiido Hm, okay. I'll give it a shot - I am still relatively new to web dev/hybrid applications and any pseudo code would be super helpful. But thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the loading of both images is not handled correctly.
Both will load asynchronously, and while your codes is waiting for each `load` event, your code is assuming that the first image will always load first.
But given the nature of these images, it seems that the second image (`sig`) will be lighter (most pixels are transparent), and thus will actually probably load faster.

You may have not experienced this issue on the browser, because the browser had these images in cache already, and thus will take the same time to load both images.

In the era pre-Promises, a common way to handle it was to use a counter, that would get incremented at each image's load, and which will trigger an *oncomplete* callback:

```
function loadImages(urls, onsuccess, onerror) {
  var counter = 0;
  var imgs = urls.map(function load(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = incrementCounter;
    img.src = url;
    img.onerror = onerror;
    return img;
  });
  function incrementCounter(evt) {
    if(++counter === urls.length) {
      onsuccess(imgs);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

loadImages([
  // a quite big 3000 x 2000 picture by Arturo Mann
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Sunset_over_The_Pacific_Ocean_at_Acapulco_1.jpg',
  // a small 32x32 image
  'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png'
  ], oncomplete, onerror);

function loadImages(urls, onsuccess, onerror) {
  var counter = 0;
  var imgs = urls.map(function load(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = incrementCounter;
    img.src = url;
    img.onerror = onerror;
    return img;
  });
  function incrementCounter(evt) {
    if(++counter === urls.length) {
      onsuccess(imgs);
    }
    // only for demo
    console.log('successfully loaded', evt.target.src);
  }
}

// our callback
// in here we receive the img elements,
// in the order we did set the urls
// whatever was the first to load
function oncomplete(imgs) {
  canvas.width = imgs[0].width/8;
  canvas.height = imgs[0].height/8;
  ctx.scale(0.125, 0.125);
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[0], 0,0);
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.scale(8, 8);
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[1], 176, 100);
}

function onerror(err) {
  console.error('failed to load resources');
}
```

But since you seem to be in a context that do support Promises and ES6, you can simply promisify the loading, and wait for a *Promise.all* of these loadings.

```
Promise.all([loadImage(url1), loadImage(url2)])
  .then(oncomplete)
  .catch(onerror);

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => Object.assign(
    new Image(),
    {
      onload: (evt)=>res(evt.target),
      onerror: rej,
      src: url
    }
  )
 );
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// a quite big 3000 x 2000 picture by Arturo Mann
var url1 = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Sunset_over_The_Pacific_Ocean_at_Acapulco_1.jpg';
// a small 32x32 image
var url2 = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png';


Promise.all([loadImage(url1), loadImage(url2)])
  .then(oncomplete)
  .catch(onerror);

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => Object.assign(
    new Image(),
    {
      onload: (evt)=>res(evt.target),
      onerror: rej,
      src: url
    }
  )
 );
}

// our callback
// in here we receive the img elements,
// in the order we did set the urls
// whatever was the first to load
function oncomplete(imgs) {
  canvas.width = imgs[0].width/8;
  canvas.height = imgs[0].height/8;
  ctx.scale(0.125, 0.125);
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[0], 0,0);
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.scale(8, 8);
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[1], 176, 100);
}

function onerror(err) {
  console.error('failed to load resources');
}
```